# jquery Flot js Set selection wont work propely

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I want to set selection on the last few ticks on my chart but I can't perform that, I tried function called `setSelection`  with failure, and few other ways found here or in examples but simply I can't get it to start working.

Here's my flot config.

```
{
    series: {
            lines: { show: true },
            shadowSize: 0
            },
    crosshair: { mode: "x" },
    points: { show: true },
    xaxis: {
            //zoomRange: [0, 0],
            mode: "time",
            tickLength: 5,
            panRange: [null, null]
           },
    selection: { mode: "x" },
    grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: false,
            markings: weekendAreas
          },
    yaxis: {
            //zoomRange: [0, 0],
            //panRange: [36, 39.5]
            panRange: false
           },
    zoom: {
            // 'amount': 2,
            // 'center': { left: 400, top: 0 }
            //interactive: true
          },
    pan: { interactive: true } 
});

//setSelection({ xaxis: { from: 0, to: 10 }, yaxis: { from: 10, to: 20 } });
plot.setSelection({ xaxis: { from: 5, to: 8 }});
```

Comment: Thanks, i figured out where was the problem, it's needed to set min and max values on xaxis. Thanks for reply.

Comment: If you solved the problem, please post an answer to your own question.